# Add "suggest edits" to the Privileges page and/or add "Who can make edits?" to the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Under a new answer to [How do new users discover Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269693/how-do-new-users-discover-stack-overflow/), VLAZ left [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269693/how-do-new-users-discover-stack-overflow#comment741554_391550):

> ...I even went through the privileges page bud didn't see anything about gaining a suggest edit privilege, only stuff about "now you can create community wikis that are easier to edit" or "you can directly edit posts" (the 2k rep one).

The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) does tell new users they can edit, but users probably aren't likely to go back to the tour for help using the site if they've already seen it. The Help Center does state that anyone can edit but it's under *Who makes sure that proposed edits are good?* on [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). It makes sense for it to be on that page but not in that section.

I think we can make it easier find out that anyone can make edits by putting that information in at least one of two places:

**The Help Center**
Add a section called "Who can make edits?" under *When should I edit posts?*. It should state anyone can suggest an edit, even visitors without Stack Overflow accounts. (It can also explain that edits made while not logged in are shown as an edit from Anonymous and can't be associated with an account after the fact.)

**The Privileges Page**
At the bottom, under create posts, add an entry for "suggest edits" with the required reputation being 1.

I originally suggested 0 or N/A for this to indicate that you don’t need an account but Cody’s comment reminded me that you don’t need an account to create a post either. So it should actually be 1, like the create post privilege, for consistency.

Comment: Isn't the "edit" link under each post already a pretty good indicator that they can edit something?

Comment: @Tom Sure, but [some people miss it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269693/how-do-new-users-discover-stack-overflow/#comment741611_391550) and higher rep users sometimes [forget when they earned a privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269693/how-do-new-users-discover-stack-overflow/#comment741554_391550). That said, I won't be surprised if others thing this isn't worth making a change to fix. I just think it makes sense to make it explicit in a place people would expect to find it.

Comment: It isn’t a privilege, though… *Everyone* can do it, including anonymous users. So I’m not sure how it would fit into the presentation on the privileges page.

Comment: I don't spell my name with an X :( But I suppose it's only fair after I spelled "but" with a **d**.

Comment: @CodyGray it can be listed it as "[✔ 0 - Suggest an edit to posts.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)"

Comment: Well everyone (with an account) can also “create posts” but there’s still a [privilege listed for that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts).

Comment: @VLAZ Next Meta question: "How do I get a 0 reputation score so that I can suggest edits?"

Comment: @CodyGray You just reminded me that you can create anonymous posts too (at least on main). Edited my post so it says the rep should say “1” for consistency.